# PHP - Is resizing an image with GD library sufficient for blocking/destroying code embedded within the image?

Tags: php, gd

I can't find the link I was reading earlier, about people hiding code within an image, but the premise was that executable code can be stored within an image, and then the code is run when the image is displayed on a website.

This isn't the same as:

```
<img src="www.somelink.com/image.php?q=12345" />
```

where it is obvious that the image is coming from a `PHP` file, but rather the (potentially) nefarious code is hidden within the image data itself.

Anyhow!

The article I was reading mentioned adding the slightest filter to the image (i.e. an imperceptible blur) to essentially wreck the code, and prevent it from executing.

Would this same effect be achieved from simply resizing the image, using PHP's GD library? Something like:

```
$src = imagecreatefromgif($fileTempLoc);

$resized_file1 = 'new_image_name.png';
$tmp1 = imagecreatetruecolor(a, b);
imagecopyresampled($tmp1, $src, 0, 0, e, f, a, b, c, d);
imagesavealpha($tmp1, true);
imagepng($tmp1, $resized_file1);

unlink($tmp1);
unlink($fileTempLoc);
```

Or perhaps there is a different method that is more commonly used and accepted in the industry?

What is this "embedded code" attack normally referred to as? So that I might look further into blocking/preventing similar attacks.

Much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I keep writing comments so rather than having a pile of comments I have collected them into this answer:

**How to stop scripts and nefarious code being saved into your uploaded images** (extremely brief summary)

What you need to do is in the PHP code save [the uploaded] image as several different types, in turn, such as save the image as a JPEG, then load that JPEG image resource and resave it as a PNG resource to file and then load and resave that PNG as a (final) JPEG.

Repeating this cycle (although just JPEG -> PNG -> JPEG is *probably* enough) my not do any harm but will increase processing server load.

Adding another reliable image format will also improve security (although a well supported third true-colour format I've not found, yet) as well as doig actions such as storing only the image *output* as a new file, rather than theimage *source*.

**What bad things are called and what they can do**

The reference code you are looking for is script attacks hidden in metadata most typically in JPEG files however there are other types of attacks in other filetypes such as PNG.

**Some reference readings:**

- [PNG Embedded – Malicious payload hidden in a PNG file](https://securelist.com/blog/virus-watch/74297/png-embedded-malicious-payload-hidden-in-a-png-file/)
- [PHP Code injection in a JPG image](http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/05/13/php-code-injection-a-simple-virus-written-in-php-and-carried-in-a-jpeg-image/)
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32580/what-is-the-next-step-of-this-file-upload-attack
- [How to ensure files uploaded by users do not contain any javascript](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57832/how-to-ensure-that-files-uploaded-by-users-do-not-contain-any-javascript)
- [How can I be protected from picture vulnerabilities](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8587/how-can-i-be-protected-from-pictures-vulnerabilities)

Comment: Converting between image formats is an incredibly silly and wasteful approach. It is also likely to reduce the quality of images due to recompression, and destroy transparency effects in uploaded PNGs.

Comment: I disagree, and have read topics on SO (or security stackexchange) that state as such, that the PHP loads a JPEG image, and then saves it as a PNG image, therefore cutting out the JPEG metadata which can contain nefarious codeblocks, the image is not reduced in quality as the quality of the resaved image can be set in the code. (transparency saving can be an issue perhaps)